# import data into H2 via API

Tags: html

I'm a programming beginner. . Now I'm having a problem that I struggle to solve ... I want to write a numeric data in the H2 tag that I import via API call. I have tried in various ways, making a console log the data exists but it seems that I am wrong something to richamarlo in H2. I seek help in understanding and resolving this error. Thank you

```
enter code here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
      const intervalTime = 10 * 1000;
     const container = document.getElementsByClassName("u-text u-text-palette-3-base u-title u-text-3");
    const endpoint =      "https://*************/v0/*******/************************/collections/****************?offset=0&limit=unlikely";
    function onInterval() {
      fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer **********************" }
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const title = data.records.map((a) => {
            return{
              close: (a.close)
            };
          });
          const lastClose = title[title.length - 1];
        console.log(lastClose);
        });
      }
      onInterval();
      window.setInterval(onInterval, intervalTime);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2><p class="u-text u-text-palette-3-base u-title u-text-3"></p>
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. A h2 may not contain a p element

Comment: hi, even if I remove <p> from the H2 tag, it doesn't work .. why if I call the class, I don't get the API call data?

Comment: Not my point. Didn't say it would fix anything. I'm saying you are violating the HTML standard.